# Initialise Akka ActorRef with the same state as previous one

Tags: java, akka

How do I share the state of `balance` between AkkaActors?

I understand how to initlise an Actor using props but whenever I create that Actor it'll new up a new Actor with the same values. Can I use the same ActorRef twice? When I've tried to reuse the same ActorRef by creating outside the `for` it just delivers dead letters.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("bank-system");
        ActorRef bankAccount;

        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int num;
            OptionalInt randomVal = rnd.ints(-1000, 1000).findFirst();
            if (randomVal.isPresent()) {
                num = randomVal.getAsInt();
            } else {
                num = i;
            }
            bankAccount = system.actorOf(BankAccount.props(100), "bankAccount-" + i);
            // Something not sending correctly
            if (num > 0) {
                bankAccount.tell(new DepositMessage(num), ActorRef.noSender());
            } else {
                bankAccount.tell(new WithdrawMessage(num), ActorRef.noSender());
            }
        }

        system.terminate();
    }

    public class BankAccount extends AbstractActor {
        private int balance;

        public BankAccount(int balance) {
            this.balance = balance;
            System.out.printf("Bank account initialised with £%d%n", balance);
        }

        public static Props props(int balance) {
            return Props.create(BankAccount.class, () -> new BankAccount(balance));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the point of an actor is that it encapsulates its state.  It can *tell* another actor about its state by sending a message, but that's not really the same thing as sharing its state: by the time that other actor processes the message there's no guarantee that the sending actor hasn't changed its state in some way.

You can definitely create an actor outside of the loop and save the resulting `ActorRef` in a variable (or even a collection, e.g. a `HashMap`).  The actor will maintain its state from message to message.

Your code for `BankAccount` doesn't, however process any `DepositMessage`s or `WithdrawalMessage`s, so that is likely why you're seeing messages delivered to dead-letters.

For instance:

```java
@Override
public Receive createReceive() {
    return receiveBuilder()
        .match(DepositMessage.class, dm -> {
            // Deposit never fails (assuming it's non-negative)
            System.out.printf("Depositing £%d%n", dm.getAmount());
            balance += dm.getAmount();
        })
        .match(WithdrawalMessage.class, wm -> {
            int amount = -wm.getAmount();
            if (amount > 0) {
                System.out.printf("Attempting to withdraw £%d%n", amount);
                if (amount <= balance) {
                    System.out.println("Successfully withdrew £%d%n", amount);
                    balance -= amount;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Overdraft of £%d rejected%n", amount - balance);
                }
            }
        });
}
```